# Updating a listview inside a fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Within my `ListFragment` I have this:

```
private SelectedItemListAdapter selectedItemListAdapter;
public void initSelectedItemListAdapter(CellItem[] itemList)
{
  selectedItemListAdapter = new SelectedItemListAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), R.layout.listview_item_selecteditem, itemList);
  setListAdapter(selectedItemListAdapter);
}
```

Calling this method allows me to set the data in my `ListView` however everything I've tried to update this data has failed so far. The only way I have managed to get it to work is to create a new instance of `SelectedItemListAdapter` which I don't think is very efficient.

One attempt I tried was to use:

```
public void updateSelectedItemListAdapter(CellItem[] newList)
{
  selectedItemListAdapter.clear();

  for(int i = 0; i < newList.length; i++)
    selectedItemListAdapter.add(newList[i]);

  setListAdapter(selectedItemListAdapter);
  selectedItemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

However this gives me a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. I also read about running this on the main thread, however it gives me the same exception.

I also noticed that if the `newList` has a different count to the previous, I get `java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which suggests I'm missing something to refresh the data source.

As requested, here is my `SelectedItemListAdapter`:

```
public class SelectedItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CellItem>
{
  Context context;
  int layoutResourceId;
  CellItem data[] = null;
  private static final int ROW_ITEM = 0;
  private static final int ROW_VIEWTYPE_COUNT = 1;

  class CellItemHolder
  {
    LinearLayout rootLayout;
    TextView itemName;
    TextView itemValue;
  }

  public SelectedItemListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CellItem[] data)
  {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View row = convertView;
    CellItemHolder holder = null;
    CellItem item = getItem(position);

    if(row == null)
    {
      holder = new CellItemHolder();

      LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
      row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

      holder.rootLayout = (LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.itemlist_rootLayout);
      holder.itemName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.selectedItem_name);
      holder.itemValue = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.selectedItem_value);

      row.setClickable(true);

      row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
      holder = (CellItemHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemName.setText(item.itemName);
    holder.itemValue.setText(item.itemValue);
    holder.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    return row;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount()
  {
    return data.length;
  }

  @Override
  public int getViewTypeCount()
  {
    return ROW_VIEWTYPE_COUNT;
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemViewType(int position)
  {
    return ROW_ITEM;
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can update my list adapter?

Comment: Don't hesitate to also add the code for your adapter.

Comment: I've just added that in!

Comment: Where is the add method of the SelectedItemListAdapter?

Comment: Do you mean the method (`updateSelectedItemListAdapter`) that calls `selectedItemListAdapter.add(newList[i]);`? The method is called from my `ListFragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However this gives me a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. I
>   also read about running this on the main thread, however it gives me
>   the same exception.

This has nothing to do with the main UI thread is adapter related. The thing is that you use an adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` passing it an array of data. The super class `ArrayAdapter` will take that data array and transform it into a `List` for which the `add()` and `remove()` methods are not implemented. Not having those methods means your adapter will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` when attempting to `clear` or `add` elements(method available starting with API level 11 so be carefull) to it(what you're trying to do) as it uses those methods of the list.

The solution is to use a normal `ArrayList`(or other `List`) instead of the array of `CellItem` and pass that to the `ArrayAdapter`(which will be able to modify it).

> I also noticed that if the newList has a different count to the
>   previous, I get java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException,
>   which suggests I'm missing something to refresh the data source.

I don't know what is causing this, your code should throw the `UnsupportedOperationException` exception before any boundaries overstep.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea why I was using a array instead of a list anyway! :D

Comment: @ing0 As a side note, if you're going to override most of the methods of the `ArrayAdapter` you might as well extend `BaseAdapter` and avoid other possible issues.